# Substitute shell variable references in a file with their values

Tags: bash, sed

I can replace placeholders (named after the variable name) in a file using sed :

```
ID="toto"
SECRET="tata"
sed -i -e "s/\${ID}/$ID/" -e "s/\${SECRET}/$SECRET/" $file
```

It replaces this :

```
$clientId = '${ID}';
$clientSecret = '${SECRET}';
```

with

```
$clientId = 'toto';
$clientSecret = 'tata';
```

I'm trying to make this work through a loop using arguments :

```
ID="toto"
SECRET="tata"
OTHER="franck"
./config.sh $file $ID $SECRET $OTHER
```

**config.sh**

```
for var in "${@:2}"; do
  echo "$var" # toto or tata or franck
  echo $!{var} # always var whatever I try, would like ID or {SECRET} or ${OTHER} 
  SETTINGS="$SETTINGS -e "s/\${var}/$var/"" # so this has no effect  
done

FILE=$1
sed -i $SETTINGS $FILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your config.sh a little bit to fix the issues:

```
# grab the output file name
file=$1
shift
# loop through the rest of args which are names of variables that
# need to be substituted
for var in "${@}"; do
  # note: ${var} and ${!var} do get evaluated inside single quotes so long as 
  # there are enclosing double quotes around them
  sed_expr=${sed_expr}" -e 's/\${$var}/${!var}/'"
done

# enclose sed_expr as well file in double quotes to prevent
# word splitting and globbig
sed -i "$sed_expr" "$file"
```

And invoke it as below. Need to pass variable names and **not** their values:

```
export ID="toto" SECRET="tata" OTHER="franck"
./config.sh file ID SECRET OTHER
```

Or if you don't want to do an `export`:

```
ID="toto" SECRET="tata" OTHER="franck" ./config.sh file ID SECRET OTHER
```

`sed` expression generated by the script:

```
-e 's/${ID}/toto/' -e 's/${SECRET}/tata/' -e 's/${OTHER}/franck/'
```

Your file after the above call:

```
$clientId = 'toto';
$clientSecret = 'tata';
$publication = 'franck';
```

Comment: Although the `sed` command doesn't work inside a script despite `$sed_expr` being exactly as expected, I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `-'`. When I run the exact same output command in a terminal it works as expected. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Solved it by removing the single quotes, the `e` option and executing the `sed` command in the loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the `sed` script you want to run using `sed` to edit the data into a series of `sed` commands, then use `-f /dev/stdin` to give the script to `sed` (which avoids having to clean up temporary files behind yourself).

```
FILE="$1"
shift
printf '%s\n' "$@" |
sed 's/^\([A-Z][A-Z]*\)=\(.*\)/s%\\${\1}%\2%/' |
sed -i.bak -f /dev/stdin "$FILE"
```

The null backup suffix notation doesn't work with BSD (macOS) `sed`, so I substituted `.bak` as the suffix.

This assumes the invocation is of the form:

```
file="data"
ID="toto"
SECRET="tata"
OTHER="franck"
./config.sh $file "ID=$ID" "SECRET=$SECRET" "OTHER=$OTHER"
```

The names and the values must both be provided.  Given a data file `data` containing:

```
$clientId = '${ID}';
$clientSecret = '${SECRET}';
$publication = '${OTHER}';
```

the output file is:

```
$clientId = 'toto';
$clientSecret = 'tata';
$pulication = 'franck';
```

The generated script is of the form:

```
s%\${ID}%toto%
s%\${SECRET}%tata%
s%\${OTHER}%franck%
```

You can use any unused character in place of the `%` symbol; a control character such as <kbd>Control-A</kbd> can be very effective.